# Disable (remove) the marketing menu option in WooCommerce 4.3.x

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, hook-woocommerce

Since the release of WooCommerce `4.3.x`, the previous fix for removing the Marketing menu option that worked with `4.1.x` does not work anymore and I'm wondering if anyone knows how to remove it for `4.3.x`.

I've tried all of these without success:

**#1:**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_marketing_menu_items', '__return_empty_array' );
```

**#2:**

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_wc_marketing_menu_item' );
    function remove_wc_marketing_menu_item() {
    remove_menu_page( 'admin.php?page=wc-admin&path=/marketing' );
}
```

**#3:**

```php
add_action( 'admin_init', 'remove_wc_marketing_menu_item' );
    function remove_wc_marketing_menu_item() {
    remove_menu_page( 'wc-admin&path=/marketing' );
}
```

**#4:**

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_marketing_menu_items', 'remove_wc_marketing_menu_item' );
    function remove_wc_marketing_menu_item( $marketing_pages ) {
    return array();
}
```

---

None of them work with the latest WP and WC. I have no other plugins installed and I'm not using a customized child theme or anything like that.

All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [FeaturePlugin.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/packages/woocommerce-admin/src/FeaturePlugin.php) contains on line [292-301](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/packages/woocommerce-admin/src/FeaturePlugin.php#L292-L301)

```php
/**
 * Overwrites the allowed features array using a local `feature-config.php` file.
 *
 * @param array $features Array of feature slugs.
 */
public function replace_supported_features( $features ) {
    $feature_config = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_admin_get_feature_config', wc_admin_get_feature_config() );
    $features       = array_keys( array_filter( $feature_config ) );
    return $features;
}
```

So you get: (Tested in WooCommerce 4.3.1 version)

```php
function filter_woocommerce_admin_get_feature_config( $feature_config ) {   
    $feature_config['marketing'] = false;

    return $feature_config;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_get_feature_config', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_get_feature_config', 10, 1 );
```

---

Source: https://gist.github.com/isaumya/89f48dcd84cb58af1e668bb76ba2c029 - https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin/issues/4716

Available as a plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-dashboard-for-woocommerce/

Answer (score 4):

remove_menu_page( 'woocommerce-marketing' );